# JQuery get value from one class to another class data-value

Tags: jquery

I am facing a problem with JQuery data fetching directly from the User. What i want is to get the value from one class and set in another class data-value. Below is my rough structure -

[image]

Comment: on what event?can you share your code?

Comment: Can you show the code you have now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just assuming your html structure is something like :

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="text1">
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="text2">
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="text3">
    <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

What you need is an event handler for the textboxes.

e.g

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input').change(function(){
    $(this).next().data('value',$(this).val());
   });
});
```

Here is a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/25r7n54y/

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should provide HTML structure and what event should be fired. But I'll give you some sample code if you have structure like you draw above :

```
$('.black-box').each(function(index, item){ 
    var value = $(item).val(); //get value of black box
    $(item).next().attr('value', value); // set value to red box button
})
```